# Django Foreign Key ["Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."]

Tags: python, django, api, backend

The Company table has the basic contact information of the company, and the Address contains the address and geolocation of the company. These two tables are connected with a foreign key named "company_name," which is neither a primary key of both tables. I inserted some mock data of a company named "FF2" into the company table, it went great. However, when I attempted to insert "FF2" with its mock address into the Address table, I failed and received this:

company_name: ["Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."]
I tried every solution I found online, but none of them worked. Please help and be specific as possible, thank you so much!!

model.py:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    company_name = models.ForeignKey('Company', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='company_name')
    lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=6)
    long = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=6)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'address'

class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200)
    contact_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    website = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'company'
```

views.py:

```
class AddressView(APIView):
    
    serializer_class = AddressSerializer
  
    def get(self, request):
        address = [ {"city": address.city, "state": address.state, "zip": address.zip, "address1": address.address1, "address2": address.address2, "company_name": address.company_name, "lat": address.lat, "long": address.long}  
        for address in Address.objects.all()]
        return Response(address)
  
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = AddressSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)

class CompanyView(APIView):
    
    serializer_class = CompanySerializer
  
    def get(self, request):
        company = [ {"company_name": company.company_name, "contact_name": company.contact_name, "phone": company.phone, "email": company.email, "website": company.website}  
        for company in Company.objects.all()]
        return Response(company)
  
    def post(self, request):
  
        serializer = CompanySerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

serializer.py:

```
class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ['city', 'state', 'zip', 'address1', 'address2', 'company_name', 'lat', 'long']

class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ['company_name', 'contact_name', 'phone', 'email', 'website']
```

Comment: You defined `company_name` as a foreign key to `Company`, so it requires that you give it a foreign key/id of the company and not a string.

Comment: Also please rename the foreign key `company_name` to just `company`, as it relates to the whole `Company` object

Comment: @bdbd Hi! Can you be more specific on "give it a foreign key/id of the company?" I am new to Django

Comment: I'm guessing it was written like `address.company_name = 'some_company_name'`. But `company_name` in the `Address` model is a foreign key, so it needs a `Company` id.  So something like: `address.company_name = Company.objects.get(company_name='some_company_name')`

Comment: To reduce the confusion, I think the first thing you can do is to change `company_name` to just `company` in the `Address` model

Comment: 1. When a model instance is created, django will by default, generate an integer for the primary key field of the new instance. This field by default is named `id`. 2. Foreign keys referencing another model use the primary key of the referenced model. 3. After creating your company instance, get its primary key and use that primary key value as the foreign key to the company in your address instance. And as @bdbd said, use `company` instead of `company_name` since FK's reference the entire model object.